# Templates Work on Localhost but Not Production / Live Server

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I have a setup to recognize the static files and template files at the top level (above the apps folders) like so:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

...

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    BASE_DIR + '/templates/',
)
```

It works fine in the local environment, but online I get this:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /

home.html
```

What could be causing this inconsistency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

If it doesn't work, declare your template path in a variable like

```
template_path = /path/to/template

TEMPLATE_PATH_DIRS = (
template_path + '/templates',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = TEMPLATE_PATH_DIRS
```

It will work, try it.

Comment: Strange progress (this was happening before I got your answer) I get random "template not found errors -- see here: http://xyzai.com/ (keep refreshing it, it spawns random not no template errors) very strange.

Comment: did you try my method? It happens again?

Comment: When I use realpath in my settings file. It just happened. But I recommend Choice 2. Because in Django document, it said like       Django will choose the first template it finds whose name matches, and if you had a template with the same name in a different application, Django would be unable to distinguish between them. We need to be able to point Django at the right one, and the easiest way to ensure this is by namespacing them. That is, by putting those templates inside another directory named for the application itself.